# Is there a way to apply styles to CSS ::first-line pseudo-class on hover of the element

Tags: css, css-selectors, hover, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I've been tinkering with some CSS for an HTML markup. The problem I am facing is that there is a style already applied using CSS `::first-line` pseudo-class. What I want is to change the style of this first line on hover state. Is there a way to apply something like `p::first-line:hover`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to define the `p::first-line` before you can define the chain `p::first-line:hover` like so:

```
p::first-line { color: black; }  
p:hover::first-line { color: red; }
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gMRVf/6/)

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can chain them (have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/pseudo-class-selectors/)).

```
p:hover::first-line
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a jQuery version and found out, that even that won't work. In Firefox, the class has to be applied first to work on hover, as you can see in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gMRVf/3/). But WebKit completely ignores the `::first-line` on dynamic class adding.

```
<p class="hovered">Text .... </p>
```

For Firefox the class has to be set in the HTML code. Now, the following does the job.

```
jQuery('p').removeClass('hovered');

jQuery('p').hover(function() {
    jQuery(this).addClass('hovered');
}, function() {
    jQuery(this).removeClass('hovered');
});
```

But won't work in WebKit.