# How do I apply styles when hovering only the ::first-line of an element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I want to make the first line of a paragraph bold only when the user hovers over the first line of the paragraph. I tried something like:

```
p::first-line:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Please note that this question is different from another [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355972/is-there-a-way-to-add-hover-to-css-first-line-pseudo-class). The referenced question is about how to make the first-line of the paragraph bold when the user hovers over any part of the tag. My question is how to make the first-line bold when user hovers only over the first line.

Comment: It would be `:first-line` as `:first-child` only selects actual elements but I don't believe it can be hovered as required YET!

Comment: @user12137152: I'm sorry, for some reason I misread `::first-child` as `::first-line,` my (deleted) comment, and reference, was based on a misunderstanding.

Comment: @DavidThomas, it was actually my mistake, I mistakenly wrote `::first-child`. I have edited the question. Now, I have edited the question. Sorry once again. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you have tried it is correct per [the relevant CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-4/#pseudo-element-states):

> For example, since the `:hover` pseudo-class specifies that it can apply to any pseudo-element, `::first-line:hover` will match when the first line is hovered.

However, this specific feature combination is not yet implemented in any browsers (e.g. Firefox v123 and Chromium v123). Feel free to test with this Stack Snippet; when it works, you'll know your browser has implemented the feature:

```css
p::first-line:hover {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
```

In the future, browsers may support this, and this answer can be updated at that time. In the meantime, you'll need to use JavaScript to achieve that functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible for you to attach some links that specifically suggests that such features haven't been implemented in the browsers. What I mean is that, can you provide some other sources that suggest that there is no other way these browsers have implemented the above selectors in some other way, like `box-decoration-break` is implemented as `-webkit-box-decoration-break` in chrome and safari. So, they might have been implemented but with some other property name.

Comment: @user12137152 Well I can't prove a negative, other than to show you in a demo that the style, as designed by the spec, doesn't work in whatever browser you choose to run it in. I'll add one to the post. There _might_ be a bug in Chrome's or Firefox' bugtrackers; you could file one for this issue and see if it gets closed as a duplicate of an existing bug or not--that would be a way you could also find existing information on it not working, if it does exist.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I can think off as things stand with CSS at the moment is slightly hacky as it introducwa an otherwise spurious element into the DOM.

This snippet puts a span over the first line and it is hovering that that triggers style changes in the neighboring p element.

```css
span:has(+p) {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1lh;
  background-color: transparent;
  z-index: 1;
}

span:hover+p::first-line {
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Comment: At least in the embedded Stack Snippet, this also changes the kerning of the second line when the first line's kerning changes to accommodate the bold styling. In full screen view, it's even worse; the entire paragraph's kerning shifts.

Comment: @TylerH Not sure what can be done about this if the first line is to take on bold - it is almost bound to expand beyond its previous bounds. Any views?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is anything that can be done without the working group changing how the properties apply. I was simply pointing out a caveat for the particular style chosen for this implementation (in case any readers may take this code and run wild with it).